# How to find which function add style to DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have shop on Prestashop 1.6. When I scroll down my main menu go to top (fixed position). When go up there is back to default position, header. When he back some jquery function set height to 65px. This is too samll, I need more space.

I check this element by using chrome. When I set the break point I see that the height is set in jquery library. But I dont know which function is first. Who set this 65px and why ?

```
style: function(a, b, c, d) {

            if (a && 3 !== a.nodeType && 8 !== a.nodeType && a.style) {
                var e, f, g, h = n.camelCase(b),
                    i = a.style;
                if (b = n.cssProps[h] || (n.cssProps[h] = Vb(i, h)), g = n.cssHooks[b] || n.cssHooks[h], void 0 === c) return g && "get" in g && void 0 !== (e = g.get(a, !1, d)) ? e : i[b];
                if (f = typeof c, "string" === f && (e = Rb.exec(c)) && (c = (e[1] + 1) * e[2] + parseFloat(n.css(a, b)), f = "number"), null != c && c === c && ("number" !== f || n.cssNumber[h] || (c += "px"), l.clearCloneStyle || "" !== c || 0 !== b.indexOf("background") || (i[b] = "inherit"), !(g && "set" in g && void 0 === (c = g.set(a, c, d))))) try {
                    i[b] = "", i[b] = c
                } catch (j) {}
            }
        },
```

And the output:

```
a: div#block_top_menu.sf-contener.clearfix.col-lg-12
b: "height"
c: "65px"
d: undefined
e: null
f: "string"
g: {get: ƒ, set: ƒ}
h: "height"
```

How to debug this problem ?

Comment: with chrome dev tools, you can place a breakpoint on that line. Then check the stacktrace. That is all :)

Comment: Do You mean set a beark point - attribute modifications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome you can set a DOM Change Breakpoint on an element itself for when an attribute changes.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom

**Attributes modifications:** Triggered when an attribute is added or removed on the currently-selected node, or when an attribute value changes.

Top of the stacktrace should be the function you're after.